# network visualization with different colors for different edge labeled

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have a network with 3 different edge types, edgelist file is a three column file with id1, id2 and edge label. I uploaded the file [here](http://expirebox.com/download/81cee4b7cb1c630dbf3d1d5ef4032e0b.html)

What I need know is to find a way to plot this network, as undirected network, where edges of different labels appear with different colors. I was not even able to find how to read edge label from file.

I would appreciate any help/suggestion.

EDIT: few lines of the edgelist file:

```
1   230 1
1   113 3
1   493 1
1   327 2
2   94  2
3   64  2
3   192 2
3   10024   2
3   151 2
10  260 3
10  230 1
10  10216   1
10  41  1
13  295 1
13  2392    1
```

Comment: Please post here a minimal dataset that illustrates your problem.  There should be no need for anyone to download a large file (and risk malware and such).

Comment: I edited the q to include the edgelist. pasting lines here messed up the format though, all columns are separated by tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first define a function that translates your edge label into a color. You can then use this function with `Style` to plot the colored graph.

```
d = Import["..\\sample_el.txt", "Table"]; 

EdgeStyleColor[c_] := Switch[c, 1, Red, 2, Blue, 3, Green];
Graph[Style[#1 <-> #2, EdgeStyleColor[#3]] & @@@ d]
```

[image]

Comment: `EdgeColor` is a `System` context symbol.  It is probably not a good idea to attach definitions to it.

Comment: @Szabolcs My bad, but isn't `EdgeColor` depreciated anyway?

Comment: I don't actually know what it is used for, or even if it is a graph-related thing.  But if in the ``System` `` context, better not mess with it.  I don't think this is the same as ``Combinatorica`EdgeColor``.

Answer (score 4):

```
edgetypelist = {{1, 2, Red}, 
                {1, 3, Green}, 
                {2, 3, Red}, 
                {2, 4, Blue}} 

 myedgelist = 
       Style[UndirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[3]]] & /@ edgetypelist

Graph[Range[4], myedgelist]
```

[image]

If your edge type is an integer (1,2,3), then proceed as follows:

```
rawedgelist = 
 Table[{RandomInteger[15], RandomInteger[15], 
   RandomInteger[{1, 3}]}, {20}]
```

(This is the form of your raw table.)

Next create a list of edges from the vertex in the first entry to the vertex in the second entry, colored by the edge type integer (1,2,3):

```
myedgelist = 
 Style[UndirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]], 
    Part[{Red, Green, Blue}, #[[3]]]] & /@ rawedgelist
```

Then graph the list of vertexes (`rawedgelist[[All,1]]`) with the colored edges:

```
Graph[rawedgelist[[All, 1]], myedgelist]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not sure if I understand this solution. Are you suggesting that I rewrite the edge list to include the actual color name instead of numeric edge label?

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider [`HighlightGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HighlightGraph.html)

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/sample_el.txt", "Table"];

edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ data[[All, {1, 2}]];

markers = data[[All, 3]];

HighlightGraph[
 Graph[edges, VertexSize -> Scaled[0.003], VertexStyle -> Black],
 Style[Pick[edges, markers, #], ColorData[81][#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
]
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
HighlightGraph[
 Graph[edges, VertexSize -> Scaled[0.003], VertexStyle -> Black],
 MapThread[Style[Pick[edges, markers, #1], #2] &, {{1, 2, 3}, {Red, Green, Blue}}]
]
```